# Double Inner Join - Incorrect Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this SQL Query, I need to Join my VehicleMonitoring Log Table twice as I need values from Enter and Exit Events where 6 is enter and 7 is Exit.

The Problem is that Enter Time is always the same when I run this script.

```
Select top 100
    aEnter.iAssetId as AssetEnter, 
    aEnter.iAssetId as AssetExit, 
    vmEnter.dtUTCDateTime,
    g.iGeofenceId,
    g.sGeofenceName,
    c.sCategoryName,
    c.iCategoryId,
    s.sSiteName,
    s.iSiteId,
    vmEnter.dtUTCDateTime as EnterTime,
    vmExit.dtUTCDateTime as ExitTime
    --,
    --convert(char(8),dateadd(s,DATEDIFF(s,vmEnter.dtUTCDateTime, vmExit.dtUTCDateTime ),'1900-1-1'),8) as Times
From Sites s
    Inner Join Categories c on s.iSiteId = c.iSiteId
    Inner Join Assets aEnter on c.iCategoryId =  aEnter.iCategoryId
    Inner Join VehicleMonitoringLog vmEnter on vmEnter.iAssetId = aEnter.iAssetId and vmEnter.eEventCode = 6
    Inner Join VehicleMonitoringLog vmExit on vmExit.iAssetId = aEnter.iAssetId and vmExit.eEventCode = 7
    Inner Join Geofences g on g.iGeofenceId = vmEnter.iGeofenceId
```

Which join is incorrect?

[image]

Comment: The join is on iAssetID.  It looks like your results show AssetEnter (iAssetId) as the same for all records, so I'd expect the Enter Time to follow suit.

Comment: looks like your code will list all of the entry and exit times, how do you know that the exit is related the a given entry?

Comment: I agree with mrtig. You need to define the relationship between the two aliases for vehicleMonitoringLog.

Comment: An asset can have more than one VehicleMonitoringLog with eEvent 6 or eEvent 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a cross product between Assets and the two Vehicle tables.

if you didn't stop at top 100 you'd see after a while Entertime would change and be the same again for a while.

You need to have two asset tables as well as 2 VehiclMontioringLog tables.  One for the AssetEnter and one for AssetExit.

```
Select top 100
aEnter.iAssetId as AssetEnter, 
aExit.iAssetId as AssetExit, 
vmEnter.dtUTCDateTime,
g.iGeofenceId

From Sites s
Inner Join Categories c on s.iSiteId = c.iSiteId
Inner Join Assets eEnter on c.iCategoryId =  aEnter.iCategoryId
Inner Join Assets aExit on c.iCategoryId =  aExit.iCategoryId
Inner Join VehicleMonitoringLog vmEnter on vmEnter.iAssetId = aEnter.iAssetId and vmEnter.eEventCode = 6
Inner Join VehicleMonitoringLog vmExit on vmExit.iAssetId = aExit.iAssetId and vmExit.eEventCode = 7
Inner Join Geofences g on g.iGeofenceId = vmEnter.iGeofenceId
```

Comment: How do I double join the Assets table and VehicleMonitoring talbe?

Comment: @DawoodAwan more like this, you need to change the select clause too